# JDBC sequential PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, postgresql, multithreading, jdbc

Doing the following test I am noticing that the PreparedStatement is running sequentially, is it possible? Is there a way to run it in parallel?

I am creating a list of Connections and then I create several threads (as many as I have connections) and run a PreparedStatement.

I'm seeing that the execution of the query may be parallel as the time I print is incremental (instead of the same approx). The first thread gives me back 3 seconds and it keeps increasing until it reaches 20-30 seconds.

```java
@Test
void test2() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MYTHREADS; i++) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://url:port/db?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=require",
                    "usr", "pwd");
            connection.setSchema("schema");
            connectionList.add(connection);
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < connectionList.size(); i++) {
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(i);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
}

private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final int connectionNumber;

    public MyRunnable2(int connectionNumber) {
        this.connectionNumber = connectionNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String sentence = "SELECT * FROM X WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ? AND client = ? ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 0;";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionList.get(connectionNumber).prepareStatement(sentence);
            preparedStatement.setObject(1, 0);
            preparedStatement.setObject(2, System.currentTimeMillis());
            preparedStatement.setObject(3, "75");

            long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            log.info("Time ({}): {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime);
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't run in parallel even though they are in different threads?

Comment: Well your JVM isn't the only microservice to be considered here; you also have to consider whether the database is running things in parallel.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the code is using a separate physical connection for each thread. So Postgres will run the queries in parallel (although I don't see a reason to do so here - but I assume this is just a proof of concept)

Comment: Please show use how you initialized your `executor`

Comment: @a_ Yes, is a proof of concept (It is a very simple extraction of what the project actually does). With pgadmin I see that there are several idle connections but none of them are making requests, so only this test would be consuming database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name private final ExecutorService exeutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

Comment: If I put a log just before the executeQuery I see that they all run in parallel, but then the time goes one by one.